# Proxy using Burp for web.whatsapp.com

Tags: whatsapp, http-proxy, burp

I set up Burp to intercept https requests. I could see the packets of all https websites like goole, facebook. The website `web.whatsapp.com` is not loading completely on using with Burp proxy. I am getting this error on webpage

> WebSocket connection to 'wss://web.whatsapp.com/ws' failed: WebSocket
>   opening handshake timed out

What may be the reason?

Comment: I noticed that WhatsApp Web failed to load with mitmproxy / mitmdump also. A workaround was to stop the tool mitmdump and start it again to see WebSocket messages.

Answer (score 0):

Like many popular apps, WhatsApp is using [certificate pinning](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/29988/what-is-certificate-pinning) which makes sniffing packages way more difficult *(as the application only trusts one certificate)*. That being said Burp Suite offers [some solutions](https://portswigger.net/burp/documentation/desktop/tools/mobile-assistant) for iOS, which unfortunately only work if your device is Jailbroken *(If this is the case [here](https://portswigger.net/burp/documentation/desktop/tools/mobile-assistant/installing) is what you have to do)*.

I hope this helps!

Comment: It looks like the OP is talking about WhatsApp Web, which is a web version so I don't think there is certificate pinning since HPKP has been removed from web browsers (at least since the end of 2019): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Public_Key_Pinning#Browser_support_and_deprecation